# Sum of 8 neighbors in 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to find the sum of all the neighboring elements of a cell, say `getsumofneighbors(matrix, i, j)`:

```
'M*N matrix'
[[0 1 0]
 [2 0 1]
 [0 4 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

sum of nearest elements of cell `[0][0]` is 3

at `[1][0]` is 5

and at `[1][1]` is 8

Is there a python lib to find the sum of all the elements next to the given cell?

Comment: The easiest (and probably fastest) way to do this is to treat it as a convolution of a 3x3 kernel of 1s, which can be done with [uniform_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter.html) in scipy, and possibly other methods too...oh, you'll have to subtract the original matrix so as to not include the value at the centre of the 3x3 kernel.

Comment: you can also just using indexing to sum the 8 offset versions, though that is a bit messy and requires multiple passes over the data in memory.  `out = np.zeros_like(A); out[1:,1:] += A[:-1,:-1];` etc.

Comment: @dan-man you're describing a solution that was posted 2 hours prior to your comment.

Comment: @piRSquared - are you referring to your solution? That's not the same as what I was saying. Both my suggestions are trying to evaluate the sums for *all* entries in the array at the same time (i.e. vectorized), whereas your answer gives the sum for one entry at a time (which may actually be what the OP wanted).

Answer (score 17):

If you don't mind the dependency on scipy, you can use [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html), as follows:

```
In [475]: a
Out[475]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [476]: kernel
Out[476]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])

In [477]: from scipy.ndimage import convolve

In [478]: c = convolve(a, kernel, mode='constant')

In [479]: c
Out[479]: 
array([[3, 3, 2],
       [5, 8, 5],
       [6, 3, 5],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: @dan-man: I guess "easier" is in the eye of the beholder.  The effective kernel of `uniform_filter` in this case is [[1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9]].  So to get the desired result, you'd have to scale the input or output by 9, and also subtract the original array.  To my eye, that isn't any easier than what I've shown.

Answer (score 5):

You can use slicing and `np.sum` to calculate the sum of a particular region:

```
def getsumofneighbors(matrix, i, j):
    region = matrix[max(0, i-1) : i+2,
                    max(0, j-1) : j+2]
    return np.sum(region) - matrix[i, j] # Sum the region and subtract center
```

Notice that the `max` is there because negative starting indexes trigger different slicing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
def sum_neighbors(A, i, j):
    rows, columns = A.shape
    r0, r1 = max(0, i-1), min(rows-1, i+1)
    c0, c1 = max(0, j-1), min(columns-1, j+1)
    rs = list({r0, i, r1})
    cs = [[c] for c in list({c0, j, c1})]

    return A[rs, cs].sum() - A[i, j]
```

#### Explanation

Slice `A` by row before and after `i` with column before and after `j`.  Take the sum and subtract cell at `i`, `j`.  All other code is to handle the edges.

#### Demonstration

```
import numpy as np

mxn = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                [2, 0, 1],
                [0, 4, 0],
                [0, 0, 0]])

for i, j in [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)]:
    s = "sum of neigbors for i={} and j={} is {}"
    print s.format(i, j, sum_neighbors(mxn, i, j))

sum of neigbors for i=0 and j=0 is 3
sum of neigbors for i=1 and j=0 is 5
sum of neigbors for i=1 and j=1 is 8
```

Comment: I believe what @Sanjeeth had asked for is the sum of the nearest cells(horizontally, vertically, diagonally). Not sum of all other cells as your code returns.

Comment: @kanayamalakar I believe that's what I've provided.  I'll add a demonstration.

Comment: Oops . Don't know why it returned wrong output when I first ran it. Anyway, sorry for misunderstanding. And thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following function should accomplish the task of finding the sum of all the neighboring elements of a cell:

```
def sum_around(matrix, r, c):
    total = 0
    offset = (0, 1, -1)
    indices = ((i, j) for i in offset for j in offset)

    next(indices, None)

    for rec in indices:
        try:
            row = r - 1 + rec[0]
            col = c - 1 + rec[1]
            total += matrix[row][col] if 0 <= row and 0 <= col else 0
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return total
```

Key points:

- offsets defines relative changes needed for given indice to get
  surrounding elements  (incl position of given indice himself because
  relative change [0][0] results in no change in indice)
- due to order of elements in offset, indices generator object created in such
  way that first item is (0, 0). First item is consumed by next()
- looping through generator object remaining elements, calculating and assigning values
  to matrix indices and adding values to total if indices are not
  negative (for    obvious reasons) and continuing when indices are
  out of range    (IndexError)
- function expects that user will enter cell location in    finger-based index
  and deduction -1 is needed for converting values to    0-based index

Answer (score -3):

Just created this function which will do the job

```
def sumofnieghbors(MatrixObj, indexR, indexC):
    upperleft = 0
    if not (indexR < 1) or (indexC < 1):
        upperleft = MatrixObj[indexR - 1][indexC - 1]
    upper = 0
    if not (indexR < 1):
        upper = MatrixObj[indexR - 1][indexC]
    upperright = 0
    if not ((indexR < 1) or (indexC >= NbofCol)):
        upperright = MatrixObj[indexR - 1][indexC + 1]
    right = 0
    if not (indexC >= NbofCol):
        right = MatrixObj[indexR][indexC + 1]
    rightdown = 0
    if not ((indexR >= NbofRow) or (indexC >= NbofCol)):
        rightdown = MatrixObj[indexR + 1][indexC + 1]
    down = 0
    if not (indexR >= NbofRow):
        down = MatrixObj[indexR + 1][indexC]
    leftdown = 0
    if not ((indexR >= NbofRow) or (indexC < 1)):
        leftdown = MatrixObj[indexR + 1][indexC - 1]
    left = 0
    if not (indexC < 1):
        left = MatrixObj[indexR][indexC - 1]
    return (upperleft + upper + upperright + right + rightdown + down + leftdown + left)
```

Comment: Please check your indentation and maybe explain what you are doing? It looks like some manual iteration, over what? Why the `left`, ... variables?