# Calculate sum of all directly surrounding elements to some element in matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sum

I am to calculate sum of all the directly surrounding elements to some element in a matrix.

```
[ [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9] ]
```

so that `sum_neighbours(matrix[0][0]) == 11` and `sum_neighbours(matrix[1][1]) == 40`.

The problem is just that I'm a beginner and I don't know how to make sum_neighbours calculate how many neighbours a certain number has.
I figured that I could write write if-elif-else-statement and then give the specific amount of neighbours that each value in the matrix has, but surely there must be a more efficient way to do this?
Otherwise it'll only be able to calculate the sum of the neighbours for matrices that are 3 x 3.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37026344/7828101

Answer (score 1):

A nice approach is to use numpy and a convolution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])

convolve2d(a, [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]], mode='same')
#                top    center  bottom
```

output:

```
array([[11, 19, 13],
       [23, 40, 27],
       [17, 31, 19]])
```

Alternatively:

```
convolve2d(a, np.ones((3,3)), mode='same')-a
# this sums the neighbours + the center
# so we need to subtract the initial array
```

###### example on a larger array and ignoring the top left neighbor

this is just to show yo how easy it is to perform similar operations when using convolutions

```
a = np.arange(5*6).reshape((5,6))
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
#        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
#        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

convolve2d(a, [[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]], mode='same')
array([[  7,  15,  19,  23,  27,  25],
       [ 20,  42,  49,  56,  63,  52],
       [ 44,  84,  91,  98, 105,  82],
       [ 68, 126, 133, 140, 147, 112],
       [ 62, 107, 112, 117, 122,  73]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to achieve this without any imports (the underlying assumption is that you have already checked that you have a well formed list of lists/matrix i.e. all the rows have the same length):

```
# you pass the matrix and the (i,j) coordinates of the element of interest
# This select the "matrix" around i,j (flooring to 0 and capping to
# the number of elements in the list - this is for the elements on the edge
# of the matrix)
def select(m, i, j):
    def s(x, y): return x[max(0,y-1):min(len(x),y+1) + 1]
    return [s(x, j) for x in s(m, i)]

def sum_around(m, i, j, excluded = True):
    # this sums all the elements within each list and compute the 
    # grand total. It then subtracts the element in (i,j) if 
    # excluded = True (which is the default behaviour and what you want here) 
    return sum([sum(x) for x in select(m, i, j)]) - (m[i][j] if excluded else 0)

m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(sum_around(m, 0, 0)) # prints 11

print(sum_around(m, 1, 1)) # prints 40
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can add an extra row and column on boundary with values 0.
Then you can easily add the neighbouring elements, without any boundary conditions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).